# Getting php array value

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i have quick question.
I have an array witch looks like that:

```
Array ( [id] => 311 [file] => [name] => Mobilny [minutes] => [connection_type] => [price] => [price_landline] => [price_mobile] => [prices] => [{"city_id":"304","months":"0","price":"1","minutes":"0"}] [link] => mobilny [page_id] => 3521 [hidden_number] => Y [position] => 0 [date] => 2016-07-26 [date_modify] => 2016-08-29 )
```

And this array has this column:

```
[prices] => [{"city_id":"304","months":"0","price":"1","minutes":"0"}]
```

My question is, is this value is treated like a string?

```
[{"city_id":"304","months":"0","price":"1","minutes":"0"}]
```

How can i access value from `city_id`? When i use `$table[0]['prices']` i get following: `[{"city_id":"304","months":"0","price":"1","minutes":"0"}]` and i don't know how to get `city_id` from it.

Comment: This is json, decode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have JSON formatted value. Decode it using `json_decode` function.

```
//Decode JSON to object
$decoded = json_decode($table[0]['prices']);
$cityId = $decoded->city_id;

//Decode JSON to associative array
$decoded = json_decode($table[0]['prices'], true);
$cityId = $decoded['city_id'];
```

Comment: I think you forgot `true` param for array

Comment: Yes that works perfectly, thank you guys. I will close this topic as soon i can.